# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using shared_preferences: ^0.5.6. I'am getting the below error when i call shared preference in workmanager.

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `flutter clean` and then uninstall the app from the emulator or your device and run it again

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error
I have flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 in yamal file
which have something nullsafety kind of prevention
so either you upgrade your sdk works but for me

it is working fine when I downgrade the facebookplugin
thanks